# Unit testing DateTime.Now

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, oop, datetime

Suppose there is class

```
class Task
{
   public DateTime StartedDate {get; private set;}

   public Task() 
   {
      StartedDate = DateTime.Now;
   }
}
```

I want to test condition that work on a task begins after the task is created. So `StartedDate` should always be *21 January* if the task was created 21 January. I'm not sure if passing some time provider to task constructor is a good idea.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I'm not sure if passing some time provider to task constructor is a good idea.

It is a good idea. References to `DateTime.Now` are considered dependencies on global state and are discouraged from being used directly. About the constructor - it may be argued that doing this inside a constructor is a bad practice as well ("doing work inside constructors"), but that is a different topic.

The best practice for testability is to create a small wrapper interface to provide the current time which can be implemented against `DateTime.Now` or mocked for tests.

While some test frameworks like Microsoft Fakes are able to replace the `DateTime.Now` getter, this is complex to set up and maintain and should only be used when needing to test legacy code.

If you happen to already be using libraries like `System.Reactive` ("Rx.NET") or NodaTime, they already have abstractions over time ( `IScheduler` for rx, `IClock` in NodaTime).